# Programmatically add uipickerview and its data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

In my view did load there is a for loop which selects data from sqlite and produce uipickerview dynamically

```
 for (int k=0; k<dataQuestions.count; k++)
{
        pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,656,768,44)];
        pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
        NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(pickerCancel:)];
        [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDone:)];
        [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

        pickerToolbar.hidden=YES;
        myPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,700,768,260)];
        myPicker.tag = [[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];
        myPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
        myPicker.dataSource = self;
        myPicker.delegate = self;
        myPicker.hidden = YES;
        [myPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        myPicker.tag=[[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];

        UIButton *buttonControl = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonControl.tag = [[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"] integerValue];
        [buttonControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"combobox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonControl setTitle:@"Seçiniz" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonControl setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonControl.frame = CGRectMake(30,sectionY + mainCategoryHeight+subCategoryHeight+questionLabel.frame.size.height +offsetQuestion,433,38);
        [buttonControl addTarget:self action:@selector(selectSingleChoice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSMutableArray *choices=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[DBHelper getSharedInstance:[LoggedinUser sharedCenter].dbFileName] getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID:[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"]]];



        _singleSelectedData= [choices valueForKey:@"choiceName"];



        [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
        [self.scrlview addSubview:pickerToolbar];
        [self.scrlview addSubview:buttonControl];


    }
```

so this is my code but the problem is it loads the last item's data to all uipickerviews 
because there is only 1 array i have

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    return _singleSelectedData.count;


}
```

EDIT:
my picker view delegate method:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
label.text = [_singleSelectedData objectAtIndex:row];
return label;
}
```

all uipickerviews must show its own data. any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: show me the code of `- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component `

Comment: your code creating every objects again and again..assing your uielements in viewDidLoad method and try to read a sqlite  data in viewWillAppear and assign it to array.

Comment: i edit my answer with adding the code of : - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

Answer (score 0):

Your `choices` array allocating and initializing in for loop for every k values. Create array out of for loop like that;

```
NSMutableArray *choices = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int k=0; k<dataQuestions.count; k++)
{
   ...
   ...

   [choices addObject:[[DBHelper getSharedInstance:[LoggedinUser sharedCenter].dbFileName] getQuestionChoicesByQuestionID:[[dataQuestions objectAtIndex:k] valueForKey:@"ids"]]];
  _singleSelectedData = [[choices valueForKey:@"choiceName"] objectAtIndex:k];
}
```

I'm outside so can't try code, not sure to work correctly. Test it and let me know what's going on please.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not the problem. the problem is there is pnly _singleSelectedData array to fill uipickerview and it loads on viewDidLoad so i try to load it in button's sender. Also i create a dictionary to load all arrays in it. value is my choices array and the key is questionID. then on button's sender (button's sender tag is also equals to questionID) i reload uipickerview. So i solved like this for now. But i am still also try to improve it